# Undefined reference errors in gcc

Tags: gcc

gcc link results with errors:

```
dns.cpp: undefined reference to '__res_querydomain'
dns.cpp: undefined reference to '__dn_skipname'    
dns.cpp: undefined reference to '__dn_expand'
dns.cpp: undefined reference to '__res_query'
```

Is there another library that I need to link to?

Comment: I added -llibresolv, but now I get: /lib/bin/ld: cannot find -llibresolv

Answer (score 4):

Adding -lresolv solved this for me.

Comment: Please dont add such solutions as answers..Please add such solutions as comments below the question itself..